# Can't get GCC's -static-libgcc working with DYLIB libraries on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, gcc, compiler-construction, ffmpeg, shared-libraries

I've installed GCC 4.6.3 into a non-system path on a Mac system and it works fine. However, GCC wants to use code from libgcc for all the binaries I compile, and running otool -L shows that these compiled programs look for libgcc_s.1.dylib in GCC's install path. I can override this by passing -static-libgcc, which just compiles the stuff needed into the binary and that's fine. The problem is this only seems to work with executables, not shared libraries. If I use GCC to compile some third-party lib I want to use in one of my programs as a .dylib, these libraries still look for libgcc_s.1.dylib in the local GCC install path *even if I specify -static-libgcc!* Needless to say, this is a problem as there's no guarantee that those libraries will find libgcc when run on some other system.

I tried this with ffmpeg. If I look at config.log, the -static-libgcc is most certainly being used. GCC is just not linking libgcc statically with the resulting dylibs. I even tried the -nostdlib, -nostartfiles and -nodefaultlibs options but they were ignored. Again, I checked config.log and they're definitely there!

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is to do with throwing exceptions across the shared library boundary.  This [page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/gcc-4.0.1/gcc/Link-Options.html) says:

> There are several situations in which an application should use the
>   shared libgcc instead of the static version. The most common of these
>   is when the application wishes to throw and catch exceptions across
>   different shared libraries. In that case, each of the libraries as
>   well as the application itself should use the shared libgcc.
>
> Therefore, the G++ and GCJ drivers automatically add -shared-libgcc
>   whenever you build a shared library or a main executable, because C++
>   and Java programs typically use exceptions, so this is the right thing
>   to do.

The rest of that sections gives a possible workaround (it appears) and that is to use the GCC driver to link your shared library, however if the statically-linked library throws exceptions you'll *probably* get a Segmentation Violation.

Comment: Thanks. The Apple doc seems to be referring primarily to C++. Everything I've tested so far has been straight C. It also says that if you're using a non-GNU linker that shared libgcc is linked by default. That's what I'm seeing. This seems like a linker issue, but when looking at GCC's -v output it does pass -static flags to LD when compiling executables and that works OK. Perhaps LD is ignoring the -static flags when it's told to compile shared libs.

Comment: I just tried to compile my own dylib as a test and it worked (libgcc was linked statically), so I know this is possible.